# Unable to match locale dependent characters

Tags: c++, regex, locale, non-ascii-characters

I need to match any word, including french ones ( with accents like é,è,ê etc).
I have set my locale to **French_France.1252** and used the flag **std::regex_constants::collate** but accented letters still don't give a match :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <locale>


void display_result(const std::string & _str, const std::regex & _rgx)
{
    if (std::regex_match(_str, _rgx))
        std::cout << "Positive match found in \"" << _str << "\".\n";
    else
        std::cout << "NO match found in \"" << _str << "\".\n";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));


    std::regex rgx("[[:alpha:]]+", std::regex_constants::icase | std::regex_constants::extended | std::regex_constants::collate);

    std::cout << "regex use " << rgx.getloc().name() << " locale.\n";


    std::string str{ "Student" };

    display_result(str, rgx);

    str = "Élève";

    display_result(str, rgx);

    rgx.assign("[[=e=]]", std::regex_constants::icase | std::regex_constants::extended | std::regex_constants::collate);
    str = "E";

    display_result(str, rgx);

    str = "É";

    display_result(str, rgx);


    std::cin.get();
}
```

**output :**

```
    regex use French_France.1252 locale.
    Positive match found in "Student".
    NO match found in "Élève".
    Positive match found in "E".
    NO match found in "É".
```

I cannot use wide char ( the string the program must parse will come from `char * argv[]` ) nor can I use boost.
Any idea on what went wrong ?
I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: "the string the program must parse will come from `char * argv[]`" So use `wmain` instead of `main`, and then the string will come from `wchar_t* argv[]`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I forgot about that, thanks.